# Recieving an error importing scipy.signal

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use scipy.signal but keep getting an error when I try to import it in my code.
I have:
import scipy,
from scipy import signal 
in my code and I have used pip install to install scipy, but I always get the error:
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. (as seen in image)

[image: error]
 I recieve when I try to run my code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reinstalling SciPy again? (with the latest version). It worked for me.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled scipy, making sure it was the newest version, but this didn't fix anything for me